# Custom Join Query in JpaRespository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In my project, I have two entities: `competition` and `user`. Users should be able to watch (favourite) competitions.

```
@Entity
public class Competition
{
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "competition_id", strategy = "de.deepsource.jpa.generator.CompetitionIdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "competition_id")
    private String id;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    private String email;

    ...
}
```

I access all `competitions` via `PagingAndSortingRepository`:

```
public interface CompetitionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository <Competition, String>, 
JpaSpecificationExecutor <Competition>
{
}
```

I fetch all paginated results via:

```
wRep.findAll(spec, pageable)
```

My question now is: How can I realise this "watching" feature?

Comment: I think i need to add a custom `@Query` method to my repository interface. However, I haven't figured out a proper way to join the two entities...

Comment: For start, explain what does it mean (favorite) in term of your domain? And provide fool User and Competition entities code

Comment: what means `(favourite) competitions` and `watching feature`? You want a custom join on what? Please specifiy. And do you have any persistence mapping between user and competition? If not start with that.